# Is "g" in "hangover" pronounced /ŋ/, /g/ or silent?

Tags: pronunciation

I've listened the pronunciation of the word "hangover" on [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/hangover), both UK and US.

I am aware that the g is pronounced /ŋ/ here and I really didn't catch the phonetic sound [g] in there.

Nevertheless, I actually heard a few of people pronounce a [g] in "hangover" (like the [g] in "game").

So, should [g] in "hangover" be pronounced or silent?

Here is [an example](https://youtu.be/_nRtCVJIToA?t=307) of a Canadian accent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in most accents, there is no separate /g/ sound in *hangover*, just the same /ŋ/ as in "hang". It is like "singer" (/sɪŋɚ/) not "finger" (/fɪŋgɚ/)

Some accents in North-West England normally pronounce a /g/ in words like "hang", and for those speakers, "hangover" also has a /g/.

Comment: In English, it's not about separateness, it's about hearing it: The town of **Hanover** versus **a hangover**. The ng is said/heard That is: /ŋ/ to provide the phonetic sound. And for finger if you remove the ng of the /ŋ/ sound, you'd get nothing, really. fier, the /ŋ/, In English, you can't make the distinction between Hanover and Hangover without it. And that's in all varieties of English. It's not like: lying pronounced lyin'.

Comment: But (in most accents) there is a significant different (apart from the initial consonant) between _singer_ and _finger_. I believe that the OP was asking about that difference. My answer addresses the difference, and yours does not. If you remove the  /ŋ/ in "finger" you get "figger", not "fier".

Comment: What has "sigger" to do with it? Except in Manchester, if you remove the  /ŋ/ from "singer" you do get "sier". And in my speech, there is no /g/ in "hangover" however much I stress it or slow it down.

Comment: In other words, ng is a minimal pair: hangover versus hanover//finger versus finder//singer versus sinner. For example.

Comment: But you are still ignoring the difference between /ŋ/ and /ŋg/, which is what I believe the question was about. I believe that the difference between /ŋ/ and /n/ is something that you introduced in your answer. It was also you that introduced the concept of "removing the /ŋ/ sound", with your false assertion that if you removed it from "finger" you would get "nothing, really, fier". Finger has /ŋg/, in all accents of English afaik.

Comment: Come on, if you remove the ng sound written phonetically as  /ŋ/, you do get: fi[ng]er. Read my link: https://pronunciationstudio.com/the-ng-sound/ The sound is: /ŋ/, not /ŋg/

Comment: But @Lambie, the word _finger_ (unlike the word _singer_ in most accents) contains the phoneme  /ŋ/ followed by the phoneme /g/

Comment: We are disagreeing about /ŋ/. For me, it is ng. I see no difference between finger and singer in most accents.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm flabbergasted. Are _finger_ and _singer_ exact rhymes for you? Do you come from North-West England?

Comment: *Whoops, you are right*: In both Received Pronunciation and General American, the IPA phonetic symbol /ŋ/ corresponds to the final consonant sound in words like "sang", "sing", "song" and "sung" and, of course -ing forms. Not all words with "ng" have that /ŋ/: cf. angle and angel. On the other hand, it should be pointed out that /ŋ/ is often, but not always, followed by /g/ cf. singer vs single or long vs longer. https://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/%C5%8B/ Indeed, you are right. Sorry. But hangover is /ŋ/ and not /ŋ/ /g/. Is my point.

Comment: My point is still: if you remove the ng sound /ŋ/ from hangover, you get:Hanover. And that ng sound /ŋ/ is the same in RP and AmE. My answer is correct.

Comment: @Lambie: your answer is correct as far as it goes, but it addresses only half the question.

Comment: You should point out that the OP has a misconception that "g" is sometimes pronounced /ŋ/. It is the digraph "ng" that is pronounced /ŋ/. Otherwise it would be /nŋ/ or /nɡ/.

Answer (score 5):

Colin Fine has already answered the question but I'm going to shed some light on its history.

Words that end with [ŋ] rather than [ŋɡ] in Modern English is the result of [Cluster simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Final_cluster_reductions) that occurred in Modern English. Word-final <ng> used to be pronounced [ŋɡ] in Old and Middle English, but due to a sound change in Modern English, it became [ŋ]. With this sound change, [ŋ] became a phoneme in English.

Examples: Hang, sing, king etc., had [ŋɡ] word-finally but they came to be pronounced with [ŋ] in Modern English (though many dialects such as West Midlands and North West England kept the pronunciation with [ŋɡ]).

[ŋg] mostly remained word-medially (in the middle of monomorphemic words):

Examples: Finger, hunger, anger, linger etc., have [ŋg] word-medially.

In most cases, word-medial <ng> in some suffixed words did not become [ŋg]. I only know two of those suffixes; *-ing* and *-er*.

Examples: Singer, singing, hanger, ringing etc.

Comparatives and superlatives have [ŋg] word-medially. They're an exception to the normal rule of thumb.

Examples: younger, longer, stronger, longest etc.

*Hangover* is a compound word of *hang* and *over*, 'hang' has [ŋ] so its compounds don't have [ŋɡ]. It seems that the [g] doesn't get pronounced in compound words.
(Note that the pronunciation with [ŋɡ] can still be heard in many dialects.

It's also explained briefly in [*Phonological variables and the sources of accent variables*](https://www.angl.hu-berlin.de/department/staff-faculty/academic/mcintyre/unterrichtsmaterialien/6-pho-variables.pdf/at_download/file)
Also see [*singer-finger split* - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#NG-coalescence)

Comment: hang and hangover are not different in terms of the NG.

Comment: @Lambie: I've never said they were. Can you explain what you're trying to say? And a downvote? Right. (Anyone can downvote like I just did!)

Comment: "It seems that the [g] doesn't get pronounced in compound words". Yes, that is incorrect. It is not Hanover, the name of a town. If you remove the g, that is what you get: Hanover. I explained all this in my answer but people downvote because they are clueless.

Comment: @Lambie: Can you distinguish between **g** and **[g]**?

Comment: No, I never confuse sounds. I may confuse a phonetic description of a sound. If you REMOVE the letters ng from hangman, you get: haman. If you remove the g, you get: hanman. And if you remove the n, you get hagman. And finally, ng = /ŋ/ is a nasal sound made in the same position as /k/ and /g/, so the tongue is raised at the back, touching the soft palate and the noise is released through the nose. as I said in my answer.

Comment: @Lambie: Once again, you're confusing sounds and letters. I've never discussed 'letters' (as you say) in my answer. Why do you think your answer got downvoted and mine got upvoted? Because you are confusing letters with sounds. **[g]** is a sound, **g** is a letter. [g] is the first sound in the word 'get'. [ŋ] is the sound at the end of 'sing'. Do you pronounce a hard g (as in 'get') after [ŋ] at the end of the word 'hang'?

Comment: If you never discussed letters in your answer, you failed to answer the question. There is no [g], the hard g of get in hangman. So, it is not that it is not pronounced, it's that the SOUND is not there. The sound is comprised of ng in letters, which is  /ŋ/. With the little tail.

Comment: I used your notation. YOUR notation. The letter g in hangman is not stand-alone. It  is part of the sound cluster ng which is notated phonetically as /ŋ/. The OP asked about the **letter** g, so I tried to answer the question as asked and first clarified that fact.

Comment: @Lambie: First, if the question was about 'letters' or 'spelling', the OP would've selected the 'spelling' tag. Second, the OP says (before I edited, you can check the edit history): "I actually heard a few of people pronounce "g" in "hangover", **like the "g" in "game"**. So, should "g" in "hangover" be pronounced or silent?" ///////////// Do I still need to explain it further?

Comment: The g in hangover is the letter. Need I explain that more? This is just silly.

Comment: @Lambie: The g in hangover is the letter, yes. But the **[g]** is not a letter.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is pronounced because otherwise it would be: hanover, like the city in Germany. The ng is pronounced. The difference is the a, not the ng.

There is also the word hangdog. If you don't pronounce the ng sound (/ŋ/),  it would sound like handog.

This type of g as in hang (/ŋ/) is pronounced: low-hanging fruit
OR The hangman.

Speakers do make the g sound as part of a "first unit", "hang" with a sort of pause, then comes over, dog or man or ing. The sound is ng.

However, it is impossible for me to describe this any better. Please listen at the site given below.

Here is a British guy doing the NG sound AKA  [ŋ]

His site states:

**/ŋ/ is a nasal sound made in the same position as /k/ and /g/, so the tongue is raised at the back, touching the soft palate and the noise is released through the nose.**

[thing, ng sound, the same as in hang](https://pronunciationstudio.com/the-ng-sound/)

In the case of thing and hanging, there is basically no difference between British and American English for the NG.

Of course,it is not like the g in giant.

Comment: OP is asking whether the sound is /ŋ/ or /ŋg/; whether there's a hard G after the 'ng' sound. The answer is no.

Comment: The answer is that the sound  /ŋ/ in hang is pronounced: Hanover versus hangover. /ŋ/= NG as in hang or sing. The sound is not written:  /ŋg/.

Comment: The presence of the G changes the sound to /ŋ/, just like the digraph 'th,' but it is not, itself, pronounced as a G.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I never said it was. I also said my answer **did not contain** the phonetic sound but I added it because people like you need to see it to believe it. It is not the presence of the g, it is the n + g together that make: /ŋ/.

Comment: Is there anything I said that warrants that kind of aggression?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you You tell me what the question is, as if I had not understood it. Isn't that "aggression"? It's true, some people are not happy unless they see the phonetics. Nothing in my answer is wrong. Nothing is misleading. There are different ways to present this. There is nothing about hard gs in my answer until I edited it so people would not bring it up.